# TypeError: Cannot read property 'create' of undefined

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

hi i just start to use mongoose and i am trying to run one part of my code but it's not working every thing looks fine but it keeps giving me the error cannot read property 'create' of unfriend I've tried other syntax but i getting same error please help meee ... i will send the code here, these two console.log is not working  console.log("helooooo"), console.log(dbArticle) and the code gives me the error i will send the schema here to and also i am getting res.send at the end on ui. at the end i should mentioned that i put this line of code in my server.js file const MONGODB_URI = process.env.MONGODB_URI || "mongodb://localhost/scraper";
mongoose.connect(MONGODB_URI);
because i want to deploy my app on heroku

```js
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

// Save a reference to the Schema constructor
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Using the Schema constructor, create a new UserSchema object
// This is similar to a Sequelize model
const ArticleSchema = new Schema({
  // `title` is required and of type String
  title: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  // `link` is required and of type String
  link: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },

  summary: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

image: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},

saved: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false
},

  // `note` is an object that stores a Note id
  // The ref property links the ObjectId to the Note model
  // This allows us to populate the Article with an associated Note
  note: [{
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Note"
  }]
});

// This creates our model from the above schema, using mongoose's model method
const Article = mongoose.model("Article", ArticleSchema);

// Export the Article model
module.exports = Article;
```

```js
const express = require ("express");
const axios = require ("axios");
const cheerio = require ("cheerio");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const db = require ("../models");

module.exports = function (app) {


    app.get ("/scrape", function (req, res){
        axios.get("https://www.newsweek.com/").then (function(response){
            const $ = cheerio.load(response.data);
    
            $("article.clearfix").each (function (i, element) {

                 // Save an empty result object
    
                let result = {};

                 // Add the text, summary, image and href of every link, and save them as properties of the result object
                result.title = $(this).children("h4").children("a").text();
                result.link = $(this).children("h4").children("a").attr("href");
                result.image = $(this).children(".image").children("a").children("picture").children("source").attr("srcset")
                result.summary = $(this).children(".summary").text();

                console.log(result)
    
               db.Article.create(result).then( function(dbArticle) {
                   console.log("helooooo")
                console.log(dbArticle)
               }).catch(function (err) {
                console.log(err)
              })
              
            });
        });
        res.send("it's working yeaaaaa")
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where is your server code from the backend ?